# How do I get Burnout Paradise's "Boosting Around the World" in-game achievement?

Tags: achievements, burnout-paradise

I'm having a having a hard time getting the x20 boost chain for the *Boosting Around the World* in-game achievement in *Burnout Paradise*.  I've tried boosting while drifting in circles.  I've tried driving around the quarry.  I've tried the Lone Peaks Stock Car Track.  I even tried to drive around on North and South Mountain Rd.  I can usually get up to x8 in all these places before stalling out.  (And to be honest, it feels like the game is forcing my boost chain to stop.)

What's the best way to get this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to get this was to use a Speed car, then start at one end of I-88 and head towards the other end, driving in the oncoming lane to constantly refill your boost bar. Just stay in oncoming and get near misses to keep your bar full. It's advised to start a Stunt Run and then try this because you will have less oncoming traffic.

Comment: Tips for making it even easier: turn off traffic or do it at night or do it during a stunt run; and se the slowest speed car.

Comment: Although it is really good fun in the PCPD in oncoming traffic in the daytime:-)